# Fetch data from a DataFrame and insert into multiple rows in SQL table by generating queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-3.x, pandas

1. Have a dataframe with edited data from table1.
2. Use that dataframe to generate SQL queries (using python) that updates specific column and multiple rows in table1 in the SQL database.
3. These queries should not have any dependency i,e must be able to run directly on the SQL database.

I CANNOT have the following.
1. When I generate my queries my python script cannot have connection strings to the SQL database.

How can I achieve that if possible. I cannot think of a way.

Comment: This sounds a LOT like homework. What have you tried?

Comment: It is not a homework! I needed to do a lot of processing on the fetched data. I did that, kept it in a dataframe and was trying to update it in the table by using connection strings. But the use case changed so I have to do the above mentioned one.

Comment: You need to add some details to this question so it is clear what you are asking. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a great place to start.

Answer (score 2):

You added a lot of superfluous information, I think.  Try the sample script below and see if it does what you want, with the obvious specific changes to do exactly what you need to do, of course.

```
# Insert from dataframe to table in SQL Server
import time
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

# create timer
start_time = time.time()
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


df = pd.read_csv("C:\\your_path\\CSV1.csv")

conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
    r'SERVER=Excel-PC\SQLEXPRESS;'
    r'DATABASE=NORTHWND;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO dbo.Table_1([Name],[Address],[Age],[Work]) values (?,?,?,?)', 
                    row['Name'], 
                    row['Address'], 
                    row['Age'],
                    row['Work'])
    cnxn.commit()
cursor.close()
cnxn.close()

# see total time to do insert
print("%s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```